# Image file storage for mobile device

Tags: java, android, mobile, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage

For my android app I am creating I have images that need to be downloaded. I am after a storage solution that is cheap/free with fast downloads.

I was looking into google cloud storage but I can't seem to get that to work, I add the libs to the project using the plugin but it still complains that its missing other libraries.

Alternatively I was looking into using the APK expansion files but from what I read it downloads the files automatically while downloading the APK which I do not want.

Ideally it would be great if I could use Google Drive or Dropbox to sync files with the device but it seems when using either one a login is required by the user. I don't want the user to have knowledge of what is being used in the background.

Any help / suggestions are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Android provides several options for you to save persistent application data. The solution you choose depends on your specific needs, such as whether the data should be private to your application or accessible to other applications (and the user) and how much space your data requires.

Your data storage options are the following:

*Shared Preferences*
Store private primitive data in key-value pairs.

*Internal Storage*
Store private data on the device memory.

*External Storage*
Store public data on the shared external storage.

*SQLite Databases*
Store structured data in a private database.

*Network Connection*
**Store data on the web with your own network server.**

So, I think the last is your way

[from here, read this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)